# Create a hive table from a file containing data in the form Map(retweet -> 0,loc -> none)

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

How do I create a hive table from a file containing data in the form

Map(retweet -> 0, location -> None, sentiment -> NEUTRAL, text -> Here's another best-kept secret of Bengaluru. Check it out!Want to share the city's secret? Send them in and we w…, language -> en, created_at -> 1528369782000, user -> BangaloreTimes1, hashtags -> [Ljava.lang.String;@6acc78cc)

Below code is generating the o/p.

```
      englishtweets.foreachRDD{(rdd, time) =>
   rdd.map(t => {
     Map(
       "user"-> t.getUser.getScreenName,
       "created_at" -> t.getCreatedAt.getTime.toString,
       "location" -> Option(t.getGeoLocation).map(geo => { s"${geo.getLatitude},${geo.getLongitude}" }),
       "text" -> t.getText,
       "hashtags" -> t.getHashtagEntities.map(_.getText),
       "retweet" -> t.getRetweetCount,
       "language" -> t.getLang.toString(),
       "sentiment" -> detectSentiment(t.getText).toString
     )
   }).saveAsTextFile("output.txt")
```

I could have directly stored it as Json (code below ) if I don't have to attach sentiment of each tweet.

```
   englishtweets.foreachRDD{(rdd, time) =>
   rdd.saveAsTextFile("output")}
```

Answer (score 0):

As we find your data requires , data cleaning or data transformations via RDD before you load it in to Hive table.

```
stackdata = sc.textFile("/user/<filepath>/stackdata.txt")
```

Map the data using 'map' transformations

```
stackmap =stackdata.map(lambda oi:(oi.split(",")[0],oi.split(",")[1],oi.split(",")[2],oi.split(",")[3],oi.split(",")[4],oi.split(",")[5],oi.split(",")[6],oi.split(",")[7],))
```

OUTPUT FOR ABOVE step:(u'p(retweet -> 0', u' location -> None', u'sentiment -> NEUTRAL', u"text -> Here's another best-kept secret of Bengaluru. Check it out!Want to share the city's secret? Send them in and we w\u2026", u' language -> en', u' created_at -> 1528369782000', u' user -> BangaloreTimes1', u' hashtags -> [Ljava.lang.String;@6acc7cc)')

Again we are reapplying map function for more transformation

```
stackremap = stackmap.map(lambda oi:((oi[0].split("->")[0],oi[0].split("->")[1]),(oi[1].split("->")[0],oi[1].split("->")[1]),(oi[2].split("->")[0],oi[2].split("->")[1]),(oi[3].split("->")[0],oi[3].split("->")[1]),(oi[4].split("->")[0],oi[4].split("->")[1]),(oi[5].split("->")[0],oi[5].split("->")[1]),(oi[6].split("->")[0],oi[6].split("->")[1]),(oi[7].split("->")[0],oi[7].split("->")[1])))
```

OUTPUT FOR ABOVE STEP:((u'p(retweet ', u' 0'), (u' location ', u' None'), (u'sentiment ', u' NEUTRAL'), (u'text ', u" Here's another best-kept secret of Bengaluru. Check it out!Want to share the city's secret? Send them in and we w\u2026"), (u' language ', u' en'), (u' created_at ', u' 1528369782000'), (u' user ', u' BangaloreTimes1'), (u' hashtags ', u' [Ljava.lang.String;@6acc7cc)'))

Final step ,

```
stackfinal = stackremap.map(lambda oi:(oi[0][1],oi[1][1],oi[2][1],oi[3][1],oi[4][1],oi[5][1],oi[6][1],oi[7][1]))
```

Your will get your resultant output in comma seperated format.

Final OUTPUT:(u' 0', u' None', u' NEUTRAL', u" Here's another best-kept secret of Bengaluru. Check it out!Want to share the city's secret? Send them in and we w\u2026", u' en', u' 1528369782000', u' BangaloreTimes1', u' [Ljava.lang.String;@6acc7cc)')

Now , you can load your data in to table.

**NOTE**:The resultant dataset we transformed are of strings , while performing Hive operations,we need to cast it to desired datatype.

*Hive Table for reference*

```
create table tweetdata(retweet varchar(20),location int,sentiment varchar(20),text varchar(20),language varchar(20),createdat varchar(20),user varchar(20),hashtags varchar(20))row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile;
```

Comment: To me it seems very complex, please see my recent edit which might help you in suggesting a simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks @AmitPorwal for the response , I see your code contains map with in a map `rdd.map(t => { Map(`  and `Option(t.getGeoLocation).map(geo` which is **not good performance**  indication,check the link.[https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/110] .Diversifying code is always good approach which enables readability.